# Conditionally assign value to sql variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to conditionally assign value to a variable in sql server, Like

```
SET SDate = Isnull((Select StartDate from SData), Select EDate from Table2)
```

If the first query return null or no record exist it should pick up value from tabl2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is pretty close.  You can write this as:

```
SET SDate = Isnull((Select StartDate from SData),
                   (Select EDate from Table2)
                  );
```

A subquery always needs to be surrounded by its own parentheses.

That said, your query presupposes that both tables have at most one row.  This does not seem like a good assumption.  If either has more than one row, you'll get a "subquery returns more than one row" error.

Comment: Thanks,I missed max(date) in the sample